# In what order when add item to "map" in swift?

Tags: swift

An example in swift tour in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH2-ID1

```
var occupations = [
  "Malcolm": "Captain",
  "Kaylee": "Mechanic",
]
occupations["Jayne"] = "Public Relations"
```

The final result of occupations is :

```
["Kaylee": "Mechanic", "Jayne": "Public Relations", "Malcolm": "Captain"]
```

My question:

1. Is var occupations a Map?
2. In what order does new item be added?

Comment: The type of `occupations` is called a "Dictionary" in Swift. But dictionaries are not ordered.

Comment: To elaborate on the second point: a dictionary is a key-value-store. It knows the value for the key "Kaylee" is "Mechanic", it cannot tell you which value is at position 7 e.g.. That is not what dictionaries are made for - they are (as Eric already wrote) unordered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The existing answers are highly likely to be confusing depending on what sort of programming background you come from.

> ```
> var occupations = [
>   "Malcolm": "Captain",
>   "Kaylee": "Mechanic",
> ]
> occupations["Jayne"] = "Public Relations"
> ```

Given that code snippet, the type of `occupations` is a [Swift *Dictionary*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID113).  As the other answers point out, a dictionary, in Swift, is a collection of key-value pairs.

Other languages have a similar data structure, but may refer to it by a different name.

- [C++'s `map` type](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/)
- [.NET's `Hashtable` type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Java's `HashMap` type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)
- [Objective-C's `NSDictionary` type](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/)

The list could go on.  But these all represent roughly the same data structure: a store of key & value pairs.

In Swift, dictionaries do not have an order.  Any perceived ordering you notice from printing or iterating over items in a dictionary is just that--perceived.  It should not be relied on.

If you need an ordered dictionary, you will need to implement it on your own.  Although I'm sure someone has probably already implemented it and you can find it on github.  A very simple implementation for an ordered pairs of data could simply involve an array of tuples, but you wouldn't be able to do the same key look up you can with dictionaries.

What is important here is that there is no defined order for data in a Swift dictionary, so any perceived ordering that is happening should not be relied on.

Comment: ok, no "defined order". Turn the 2nd question to another saying, in what rules does the new item be added ? I understood that the rule is NOT important, but there should be a rule behind this.

Comment: @Rob Heh, that just goes to show I have a loose definition of "alphabetical", I can't read, and there isn't an order.  ;)

Comment: @RoFF I don't understand your question.  There isn't an order.  Can you clarify what you're asking?  Any thing we know about how the keys & values are stored 1) does not matter, 2) is, as far as I know, an undocumented implementation detail which is subject to change anyway.

Comment: I tried many times, the output is always like this "["Kaylee": "Mechanic", "Jayne": "Public Relations", "Malcolm": "Captain"]". If there is no rules behind this, the result may changed every time.

Comment: @RoFF - Just because there are no formal rules (or at least any documented) doesn't mean it's going to behave non-deterministically. And the behavior _does_ change depending upon how you built the dictionary, so it's not just a function of the contents of the dictionary, but rather also affected by how the dictionary was built. What I'm wondering, though, is _why_ you care what order you retrieve items from an unordered collection. You would never write code dependent upon that behavior.

Comment: Moreover, because it is undocumented, it could behave differently across different machines, different compilers, etc. I am not saying it does, but it could

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

1. "occupations" is a dictionary (also known as a hash in some languages).  It is key-value paired which means that the keys are in no particular order but each unique key is only tied to a single value (which can of course take the form of an array or another dictionary, but still counts as one value assigned to one key).

"Map" is a function that takes a list (such as the keys or values of "occupations") and returns an array of the original list with a function applied to it.

For example

```
(0..<4).map({$0 + 1})
```

Returns an array of [1, 2, 3, 4] because the $0 is Swift shorthand for "the value of the original array that am currently applying this function to.

2. As mentioned in the answers above, when an item is added to a dictionary its position is unimportant, as the dictionary is not by nature sorted like an array would be.

Comment: Don't mix *hash* and *dictionary*. Hash table is common implementation of the *Dictionary* abstract data structure but there are other possible implementations, too. For example, Java has several possible `Map` implementations. In short, *dictionary* and *hash table* are not the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

To turn Eric and Luk's comments into an official answer:

Your var 'occupations' is a Swift Dictionary object.

A Dictionary in Swift (and Objective-C as well) does not have any order at all. It is an "unordered collection."As Luk says, it's a key-value store. You save and retrieve values using a key.

Your questions:

1. Is var occupations a Map?

### EDIT:

It's not called a Map in iOS, but it the equivalent of a map in other languages like C#, C++, and Java.

2. In what order does new item be added?

Dictionaries do no have any order whatsoever.

Comment: What is your definition of *Map*?  In my understanding *Map* data structure is just a different name for *Dictionary*.

Comment: It is indeed a map.  We just don't call it a map in Swift or Objective-C, but a *lot* of other very popular languages (C#, C++, Java, to name a few) all call it a "map" or "hash map".  To someone (like the OP) with a background in a language where this sort of structure *is* called a "map", it's probably significantly less confusing to just say "Yes, it's a map, but we don't call it a map."  Just like we'd tell a C# person "Yes, an array is basically what you'd call a list."